# R: {ggplot2}: How / Can I independently adjust the x-axis limits on a facet_grid plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, limits, facet

I created a faceted set of three univariate densities -- comparing MCMC methods.  Shown below

[image]

For the moment, I don't care about the tails.  So how can I change the x-axis limits on the plots above to be:

```
c(-3,1)
c(-2,0)
c(-10, -8)
```

Is this even possible?  I've already read [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/703ccbff21dec342/a49a69bad79767f5?lnk=gst&q=limit+scale+facet#a49a69bad79767f5) from 2009, but it doesn't seem to work.  Was this implemented?

Comment: For ref, I tried adding `scale.x.limits` to my facet_grid call and got: `unused argument(s) (scale.x.limits = c(-3, -1, -2, 0, -10, -8))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always allow limits to be set independently for each facet by specifying

```
+ facet_wrap(...,scales = "free_x")
```

There are also "free" and "free_y" options.

Comment: AKAIK, what you're describing is not currently implemented, but I *think* I read somewhere that something like this may be in the works for future versions. One option would be to subset your data using those limits via `ddply` and then plot the subset of your data.

Comment: What you recommended works.  So I've accepted your answer, though it isn't really what I wanted.  In the link I provided above, Hadley [mentioned](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/703ccbff21dec342/a49a69bad79767f5?lnk=gst&q=limit+scale+facet#a49a69bad79767f5) working on this in January of 2010.  So I was/am still hoping it was implemented.  **But for now, your suggestion works perfectly!** Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, [here's](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/703ccbff21dec342/a49a69bad79767f5?lnk=gst&q=limit+scale+facet#a49a69bad79767f5) the discussion I was remembering. That was over a year ago, though.