# R: How do I use coord_cartesian on facet_grid with free-ranging axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider some `facet_grid` plot

```
mt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 
mt + facet_grid(vs ~ am, scales = "free")
```

[image: plottttt]

Imagine I just want to zoom on **just the top row** in the plots above to only show the y-axes values between 3 and 4.  I could do this with `coord_cartesian()` if they weren't faceted or if I wanted to zoom on all plots, but don't have a good solution in this case.  I suppose I could subset the data first, but that is taboo for good reason (e.g. would throw off any statistical layer, etc).

(Note that the question is related to this: [R: {ggplot2}: How / Can I independently adjust the x-axis limits on a facet_grid plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574188/r-ggplot2-how-can-i-independently-adjust-the-x-axis-limits-on-a-facet-grid) but the answer there will not work for this purpose.)

Comment: `mt + facet_grid(vs ~ am, scales = "free") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3,4))` appears to work for me, or perhaps I am not understanding the question.

Comment: You could also use `facet_wrap`, in which case the x-axis is also suitably truncated `mt + facet_wrap(vs ~ am, scales = "free") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3,4))`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, the problem is that I want to scale *only the top set of plots*, not the bottom set.

Comment: Ahh.... The top row only. I see now.

Comment: How about using the `shrink` parameter in `facet_grid` and some kind of summary function dependent on `y` and the faceting variables

Comment: Hmmm, I'd just add them all manually I suppose, and set the y-axis on each plot.  I don't think it's possible unless you wanted to modify Hadley's code.

Comment: it's awkward there still exists no elegant solution to this in 2020.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old post but i was looking for the same thing and couldn't really find anything - [perhaps this is a way Set limits on y axis for two dependent variables using facet_grid()

The solution is not very elegant/efficient but i think it works - basically create two plots with different coord_cartesian calls and swap over the grobs.

```
# library(ggplot2)
# library(gtable)

# Plot
mt <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() 

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


p1 <- mt + facet_grid(vs ~ am, scales = "free") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1,6))
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)

p2 <- mt + facet_grid(vs ~ am, scales = "free") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3,5))
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# ----------------------------------------------------------
# Replace the upper panels and upper axis of p1 with that of p2
# Tweak panels of second plot - the upper panels
g1[["grobs"]][[6]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[6]]
g1[["grobs"]][[8]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[8]]

#Tweak axis
g1[["grobs"]][[4]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[4]]

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

Comment: With the recent version 2.2.1 of `ggplot2` the numbers of grobs in the list has been changed and needs to be amended in the example.

Comment: For ggplot2 v3.3.0, the code needs to be amended to be
# Tweak panels of second plot - the upper panels
g1[["grobs"]][[2]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[2]]
g1[["grobs"]][[4]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[4]]

#Tweak axis
g1[["grobs"]][[10]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[10]]

Answer (score 14):

So, this is an old question, but I wanted to share a way that I found. The simplest seems to be to add artificial points to your data, e.g. at the lower left and top right of your data for each plot. Put this information into a separate data frame, then add it to the plot with geom_point using the parameter alpha=0 to make the points invisible. Set the scaling of the axis in facet_wrap to "free_x" or "free_y", depending on what you need.

Now ggplot scales every facet separately to accommodate the invisible points that you added. A bit hacky, but works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution is based on the answer provided by [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773765/3915004). 
It differs by using a semi-automatic procedure to find the indices of the elements of the grob `g1` that need to be replaced with the elements from `g2`.

```
# library(ggplot2)
# library(grid)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs ~ am)

# modify p1 by zooming as desired
p2 <- p1 + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(3,4)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text  = element_text(color="blue"),
        strip.text = element_text(color="blue"))

p1
p2
```

Now we modify y-axis limits of top facet row. We generate two grobs `g1` and `g2` and replace the panels and y-axis in `g1` with the corresponding elements from `g2`.

The code below finds the indices of the grob elements to be replaced based on the names of the elements.

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# Replace the upper panels and upper axis of p1 with that of p2
# i.e. replace the corresponding grobs in g1 with the versions of g2
# Panel numbering goes row-wise from top left to bottom right
panels_to_replace_with_g2 <- c(1,2)

# To get names of grobs run: lapply(g1[["grobs"]],function(x) x$name)
# Use names of grobs to find out indices of g1[["grobs"]] of the panels we want to replace
# as well as for the axis ticks.
pattern_for_specific_panels <- 
  paste0("^panel-((",paste0(panels_to_replace_with_g2, collapse = ")|("),"))")
pattern_for_axes_ticks <- 
  "^GRID.absoluteGrob"

idx_panels_to_replace_from_g2 <- which(unlist(
  lapply(g1[["grobs"]], function(x) grepl(pattern_for_specific_panels, x$name))))
# > idx_panels_to_replace_from_g2
# [1] 2 4

idx_axesTicks <- which(unlist(
  lapply(g1[["grobs"]], function(x) grepl(pattern_for_axes_ticks, x$name))))

# Find out manually which of the defined axesTicks it is:
g_test <- g1
for (itr in idx_axesTicks) {
  g_test[["grobs"]][[itr]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[itr]]
  grid.newpage();grid.draw(g_test); grid.draw(textGrob(itr, just = "top"))
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
# We found out it is itr=10
idx_axesTicks_to_replace <- 10
```

Having now found out indices of the panels to be replaced `idx_panels_to_replace_from_g2` as well as the index of the y-axis element `idx_axesTicks_to_replace`. We can replace them in the following.

```
# Replace panels
grid.newpage();grid.draw(g1)
for (iter in idx_panels_to_replace_from_g2) {
  g1[["grobs"]][[iter]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[iter]]
  grid.newpage();grid.draw(g1)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}

# Replace y-axis
g1[["grobs"]][[idx_axesTicks_to_replace]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[idx_axesTicks_to_replace]]

# Render plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

If the plot is successfully modified, you can now remove the theme modifications and text color that we applied to p2 in order to make the changes better visible.

[image: modified plot]

Future `TODO`: What now lack is to increase the width of the y-axis to respect the modified axis labels