# Different y-Axis Labels facet_grid and sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'am stuck with the following problem:

I want to display different characteristics of a timeseries in one plot (with multiple subplots). To align the chart areas and for easy creation I use `ggplot2` and its `facet_grid` function.

However, I want to change just one axis label (eg. the upper plot to percent).

Furthermore, I want to resize the heights of each plot, so that the upper plot is roughly twice as large as the lower one.

Thank you very much for your help!

**Example**

```
require(ggplot2)

#simulate some data
df <- data.frame(date=c(1:1000),
              value=cumsum(rnorm(1000)),
              volume=abs(rnorm(1000)*10))

#melt for ggplot
df_melt <- melt(df, id=c("date"),measure.vars=c("value","volume"))

#plot
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_line() + 
       facet_grid(variable~., scales = "free")
```

which results in something like this:
[image]

Comment: For Q2) `g <- ggplotGrob(p) ;g$heights[[3]] <- unit(2, "null") ;
grid:::grid.draw(g)` , (where `p` is your plot). Q1) [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207419/r-how-do-i-use-coord-cartesian-on-facet-grid-with-free-ranging-axis), where the basic idea is to overwrite one of the axis labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `grobs` of your plot to do this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)

#plot
p <- ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=date, y=value)) + 
            geom_line() + 
            facet_grid(variable~., scales = "free")

# change facet heights
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p) 
g1$heights[[3]] <- unit(2, "null") 

# change labels - create second plot with percentage labels (nonsese % here)
p2 <- ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=date, y=value)) + 
              geom_line() + 
              facet_grid(variable~., scales = "free") +
              scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())

g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2) 

#Tweak axis - overwrite one facet
g1[["grobs"]][[2]] <- g2[["grobs"]][[2]]

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

[image]