# facet_grid different panel sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I try to make panel hights in facet_grid() to fit the plot - not be equal for every panel.

I found this: [Different y-Axis Labels facet_grid and sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929549/different-y-axis-labels-facet-grid-and-sizes)
Sadly it doesn't work :(

Here is my code, I'm using now

```r
dane <- tibble(
  "obszar" = c("Ludzie", "Ludzie", "Ludzie", "Ludzie",
               "Myślenie", "Myślenie", "Myślenie",
               "Zarządzanie", "Zarządzanie"),
  "kompetencja" = c("Współdziałanie", "Komunikowanie i przekonywanie", 
                    "Współdziałanie2", "Komunikowanie i przekonywanie2",
                    "Planowanie", "Wnioskowanie", "Innowacyjność",
                    "Budowanie zaangażowanego zespołu", "Inspirowanie i motywowanie"),
  "wynik" = c(3,3,4,2,3,6,5,4,2),
  "profil" = c(4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5)) %>%
  mutate(luka = wynik - profil) %>%
  arrange(obszar, kompetencja)

ggplot(dane, aes(x=kompetencja, y=wynik)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=kompetencja ,xend=kompetencja, y=1, yend=profil), color=kolor2) +
  geom_point(aes(y = profil), pch = 19, size=3, color= kolor2) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_flip(ylim=c(1,7)) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 12),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "grey80", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,1)) +
  labs(title = NULL,
       caption = "źródło: opracowanie własne", 
       x = NULL, 
       y = NULL) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, ymin = 1, xmax = Inf, ymax = 2.5, fill = kolor2, alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, ymin = 5.5, xmax = Inf, ymax = 7.0, fill = kolor2, alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(obszar ~ ., scales = "free")
```

Output gives me 3 panels of hight equal to the highest one. I would like to get panels with heights adequate to the number of segments in the plot.

[result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2UM0.png)

Comment: Could you try `facet_grid(obszar ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free_y")` instead of your `facet_grid()` and see if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: `Error in layer(data = etc) object 'kolor2' not found`.