# ggplot2: specifying different scales for rows in facet layout for bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

My data are visualized in the package `ggplot2` via bar plots with several (~10) facets. I want first to split these facets in several rows. I can use function `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()` for this. In the minimal example data here I build 8 facets in two rows (4x2). However I need to adjust scales for different facets, namely: first row contains data on small scale, and in the second row values are bigger. So I need to have same scale for all data in the first row to compare them along the row, and another scale for the second row.

Here is the minimal example and possible solutions.

```
#loading necessary libraries and example data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

trial.facets<-read.csv(text="period,xx,yy
A,2,3
B,1.5,2.5
C,3.2,0.5
D,2.5,1.5
E,11,13
F,16,14
G,8,5
H,5,4")

#arranging data to long format with omission of the "period" variable
trial.facets.tidied<-trial.facets %>% gather(key=newvar,value=newvalue,-period)
```

And now plotting itself:

```
#First variant
ggplot(trial.facets.tidied,aes(x=newvar,y=newvalue,position="dodge"))+geom_bar(stat ="identity") +facet_grid(.~period)

#Second variant:
ggplot(trial.facets.tidied,aes(x=newvar,y=newvalue,position="dodge"))+geom_bar(stat ="identity") +facet_wrap(~period,nrow=2,scales="free")
```

The results for the first and second variants are as follows:

[image]

In both examples we have either free scales for all graphs, or fixed for all graphs. Meanwhile the first row (first 4 facets) needs to be scaled somewhat to 5, and the second row - to 15.

As a solution to use `facet_grid()` function I can add a fake variable "row" which specifies, to what row should the corresponding letter belong. The new dataset, trial.facets.row (three lines shown only) would look like as follows:

```
period,xx,yy,row
C,3.2,0.5,1
D,2.5,1.5,1
E,11,13,2
```

Then I can perform the same rearrangement into long format, omitting variables "period" and "row":

```
trial.facets.tidied.2<-trial.facets.row %>% gather(key=newvar,value=newvalue,-period,-row)
```

Then I arrange facets along variables "row" and "period" in the hope to use the option `scales="free_y"` to adjust scales only across rows:

```
ggplot(trial.facets.tidied.2,aes(x=newvar,y=newvalue,position="dodge"))+geom_bar(stat ="identity") +facet_grid(row~period,scales="free_y")
```

and - surprise: the problem with scales is solved, however, I get two groups of empty bars, and whole data is again stretched across a long strip:

[image]

All discovered manual pages and handbooks (usually using the mpg and mtcars dataset) do not consider such situation of such unwanted or dummy data

Comment: For this case, you'd probably want to make two separate plots, with 4 cols and 1 row with the custom scale ranges and then use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package to arrange the plots as in the second variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used a combination of your first method (`facet_wrap`) & second method (leverage on dummy variable for different rows):

```
# create fake variable "row"
trial.facets.row <- trial.facets %>% mutate(row = ifelse(period %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 1, 2))
# rearrange to long format
trial.facets.tidied.2<-trial.facets.row %>% gather(key=newvar,value=newvalue,-period,-row)
# specify the maximum height for each row
trial.facets.tidied.3<-trial.facets.tidied.2 %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(max.height = max(newvalue)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(trial.facets.tidied.3,
       aes(x=newvar, y=newvalue,position="dodge"))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_blank(aes(y=max.height)) + # add blank geom to force facets on the same row to the same height
  facet_wrap(~period,nrow=2,scales="free")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note: based on this reproducible example, I'm assuming that all your plots already share a common ymin at 0. If that's not the case, simply create another dummy variable for min.height & add another `geom_blank` to your ggplot.

Answer (score 3):

Looking over SO I encountered a solution which might be a bit tricky - [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444013/ggplot2-facet-wrap-fixed-y-scale-for-each-row-free-scale-between-rows)

The idea is to create a second fake dataset which would plot a single point at each facet. This point will be drawn in the position, corresponding to the highest desired value for y scale in every case. So heights of scales can be manually adjusted for each facet. Here is the solution for the dataset in question. We want y scale (maximum y value) 5 for the first row, and 17 for the second row. So create

```
df3=data.frame(newvar = rep("xx",8),    
               period = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
               newvalue = c(5,5,5,5,17,17,17,17))
```

And now superimpose the new data on our graph using geom_point() .

```
ggplot(trial.facets.tidied,aes(x=newvar,y=newvalue,position="dodge"))+
   geom_bar(stat ="identity") +
   facet_wrap(~period,nrow=2,scales="free_y")+
   geom_point(data=df3,aes(x=newvar,y=newvalue),alpha=1)
```

Here what we get:

[image: barplot with fake points, fixing the scale]

Here I intentionally draw this extra point to make things clear. Next we need to make it invisible, which can be achieved by setting `alpha=0` instead of 1 in the last command.

Comment: use `geom_blank()`

Answer (score 2):

This approach draws an invisible line at the maximum for each row

```
#loading necessary libraries and example data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

trial.facets<-read.csv(text="period,xx,yy
                       A,2,3
                       B,1.5,2.5
                       C,3.2,0.5
                       D,2.5,1.5
                       E,11,13
                       F,16,14
                       G,8,5
                       H,5,4")

# define desired number of columns
n_col <- 4

#assign a row number - mmnsodulo number of colu
trial.facets$row <- seq(0, nrow(trial.facets)-1)  %/% n_col

# determine the max by row, and round up to nearest multiple of 5
# join back to original
trial.facets.max <- trial.facets %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  summarize(maxvalue = (1 + max(xx, yy) %/% 5) * 5 )
trial.facets <- trial.facets %>% inner_join(trial.facets.max)

# make long format carrying period, row and maxvalue
trial.facets.tidied<-trial.facets %>% gather(key=newvar,value=newvalue,-period,-row,-maxvalue)

# plot an invisible line at the max
ggplot(trial.facets.tidied,aes(x=newvar,y=newvalue,position="dodge"))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=maxvalue), alpha = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~period,ncol=n_col,scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: This is essentially the same approach as that provided by @astrsk, but includes the approach to calculate values

Comment: use `geom_blank()`