# Add layer without it affecting training of scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add a layer to a ggplot without it affecting the training of the scales, or at least not affecting the limits of the scale?

The use case I am working on is where I want to include a reference line but only need it if the data would naturally include the line. I don't want the scales to be expanded to include the line if the rest of the data would not otherwise require it.

Set up a example

```r
library("ggplot2")

g <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point()
```

Add a reference line at 250 horsepower.

```r
g + geom_hline(yintercept = 250)
```

[image: ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point() + geom_hline(yintercept = 250)]

If I change the data to something which does not extend as far along the y axis, the y axis is expanded to include the horizontal line.

```r
(g + geom_hline(yintercept = 250)) %+% mtcars[mtcars$cyl < 8,]
```

[image: ggplot(data = mtcars[mtcars$cyl < 8,], aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point() + geom_hline(yintercept = 250)]

What I want is some way to specify in the `geom_hline` layer that it should not be used when determining the y scale limits. Something that works for any geom/layer would be best. The result should look like

```r
g %+% mtcars[mtcars$cyl < 8,]
```

[image: Desired look of previous plot]

I am aware that I can manually set the y axis limits. But that does not solve my general problem because I don't know what the axis limits would otherwise be without the additional horizontal line layer.

I think it should be possible. In the [examples in the documentation for `layer_spatial`](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggspatial/man/layer_spatial.html), it mentions that `annotation_spatial` "layers don't train the scales, so data stays central", but I don't see a way to generalize that.

I have seen the question [ggplot2: Adding a geom without affecting limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907589/ggplot2-adding-a-geom-without-affecting-limits) that is the same general question, but the answer there is specific to the added layer because of scaling the values within the layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could substitute an `annotation_custom` (which doesn't train the scales) in place of a `geom_hline`. In your case it would be:

```r
g <- g + annotation_custom(
      grid::linesGrob(y = unit(c(0, 0), "npc")), ymin = 250, ymax = 250)
```

So now:

```
g
```

[image]

but

```
g %+% mtcars[mtcars$cyl < 8,]
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a more generic solution that would work with any `geom` or `stat`, but it seems that is not possible. This solution works for the horizontal lines I need, and can be generalized to anything where what needs to be drawn is simple enough to specify the `grob`s for directly.

Comment: @BrianDiggs I know it's not ideal. It would be straightforward to write a wrapper around it to cover the common use cases though. I guess it would be nice if that was written in to ggplot already.