# Zoom in on single facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

**EDIT**: 
I've read through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207419/r-how-do-i-use-coord-cartesian-on-facet-grid-with-free-ranging-axis) but that does not(in my opinion) readily solve the problem. Also considering, it's a bit old; perhaps someone has come up with a hack that does not need one to do more "hacking".

Given some dummy data below:

```
dummy_df<-data.frame(A=runif(50,0,5),B=runif(50,5,90),Group=c(1,2))
dummy_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(A,B))+geom_point()+
  facet_grid(.~Group)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,3))
```

Current plot:
[image]

How could one apply the last call to only a single facet say only facet 1 of this plot?! I would name it something like `zoom_at(facet_1)`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: How do I use coord\_cartesian on facet\_grid with free-ranging axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207419/r-how-do-i-use-coord-cartesian-on-facet-grid-with-free-ranging-axis)

Comment: why not just filter dummy_df to inlcude only one group before calling ggplot?

Comment: @adibender That's an option. However, this came into my head as I was trying to make some plots. I thought it would be great to find a way to do it.

Comment: You can also check out the package `gridExtra`. I am not very familiar with it, but It could have some functionalities to tackle your problem

Comment: You might try `patchwork` or `cowplot` to make the plots separately with the limits you want, then stick them together. You can style them to look more or less the same as facets but with your specified limits

Answer (score 1):

maybe not exactly what you are looking for but it might open up another way how to approach it

```
library(ggforce)
library(tidyverse)
dummy_df<-data.frame(A=runif(50,0,5),B=runif(50,5,90),Group=c(1,2))

dummy_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(A,B))+geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(Group)))+
  facet_zoom(zoom.data = Group =='2', xlim=c(1,3))
```